# C# - Model is always getting its default values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, modelbinders

I have an `ASP.Net Core 2.1` application.

Below is my DTO

```
public class Movie
{
  public int Id { get; set;}

  public bool IsSpecial {get; set;}

  public IEnumerable<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

    public Movie()
    {
        if(IsSpecial)
        {
            this.Tickets = new List<TicketSpecial>();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Tickets = new List<Ticket>();
        }
    }}}
```

Tickets (Base Class)

```
 public class Ticket
 {
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public string Name { get; set;}

   public decimal price { get; set;}
 }
```

TicketsSpecial (Child/Derived Class)

```
 public class TicketsSpecial : Ticket
 {
    public string SpecialProp1 { get; set;}

    public string SpecialProp2 { get; set;}

 }
```

WebAPI Controller

```
public class MovieController : ControllerBase
{

  public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Movie movie)
  {
  }
}
```

Postman (HTTPPost Req payload `Content-Type = application/json`)

```
{
"IsSpecial": true,
"SpecialProp1": "Mumbai Test",
}
```

**When I call the above API via Postman & debug at Movie ctor, it always catches the value of `IsSpecial = false` & all fields default value (ex. for string type null)**

Thanks!

Comment: `IsSpecial` will always be false during construction, you need to pass its value to the constructor or change the property's setter to build the collection.

Comment: What is the http request you are making?

Comment: Show how you are calling it through Postman

Comment: @ALFA, added the details

Comment: in the json request, try writing the propertynames with lowercase like: isSpecial and specialProp1

Comment: If I were you I wouldn't bother creating a hierarchy of model classes, just create one Ticket model handling both cases (standard and normal).

Comment: Since `TicketSpecial` is a subclass of `Ticket`, there is no need to create a different type of list to hold them. Just always create `List<Ticket>`.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the way the request is created, `IsSpecial` hasn't been initialized yet when `if(IsSpecial)` is executed

Comment: @vc74 wondering when the model get the passed values ?

Comment: @Kgn-web First a movie instance is created (using the constructor) then, once the constructor has been fully executed, the properties are initialized using their setters

Answer (score 0):

Change "Isspecial" to "isSpecial", same with the other property.

Another problem is that you're checking "IsSpecial" in the constructor and at this time it should be false anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your current implementation. First, your request json is invalid for nested properties and json deserializer would not deserialize for you with `TicketsSpecial`.

Follow steps below for a workaround:

1. `Movie`

   ```
   public class Movie
   {
           public int Id { get; set; }

           public bool IsSpecial { get; set; }

           public IEnumerable<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

   }
   ```
2. `MyJsonInputFormatter`

   ```
   public class MyJsonInputFormatter : JsonInputFormatter
   {
           public MyJsonInputFormatter(ILogger logger, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, ArrayPool<char> charPool, ObjectPoolProvider objectPoolProvider, MvcOptions options, MvcJsonOptions jsonOptions) : base(logger, serializerSettings, charPool, objectPoolProvider, options, jsonOptions)
           {

           }
           public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
           {
           var result = await base.ReadRequestBodyAsync(context);
           if (result.Model is Movie movie && movie.IsSpecial)
           {
                   context.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                   string request = await new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                   var tickets = JObject.Parse(request)["Tickets"].ToObject<List<TicketSpecial>>();
                   movie.Tickets = tickets;
           }
           return result;
           }
   }
   ```
3. Register `MyJsonInputFormatter`

   ```
   services.AddMvc(o =>
   {
           var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
           var customJsonInputFormatter = new MyJsonInputFormatter(
                           serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<MyJsonInputFormatter>(),
                           serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>().Value.SerializerSettings,
                           serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                           serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ObjectPoolProvider>(),
                           o,
                           serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>().Value
                   );

           o.InputFormatters.Insert(0, customJsonInputFormatter);
   })
   ```
4. Request

   ```
           {
                   "IsSpecial": true,
                   "Tickets":  [
                                   {"SpecialProp1": "Mumbai Test"}
                           ]
           }
   ```